# Methods of searching for Facebook groups by keywords

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to use the Facebook graph API to search for Facebook groups by keyword. I've used

search?q=keyword&type=group

in the graph API explorer and it works well, however it requires I generate a user access token. I've also read the below on the facebook API documentation

"There is another method to make calls to the Graph API that doesn't require using a generated app token. You can just pass your app id and app secret as the access_token parameter when you make a call:

http://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&access_token=app_id|app_secret"

However when I try this method it errors out with

"{"error":{"message":"(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}"

I cant understand why this needs a user access token. The search I want to perform has nothing to do with any users I just want a list of matching groups.

How can I perform this search as my facebook app from my server?

Answer (score 0):

According to the specific search documentation, you need a User Access Token.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

> All Graph API search queries require an access token included in the request. The type of access token you need depends on the type of search you're executing.
>
> - Searches across Page and Place objects requires an app access token.
> - **All other endpoints require a user access token.**