# Searching for facebook groups by keyword using the graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I wanted to find some facebook groups based on keywords and with a particular number of total members. So I was trying to fetch this data using the graph API. I tried this on the graph explorer:

search?q=keyword&type=group

Using user access token. I get the error:

"message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
"type": "OAuthException"

I created an app on facebook and I used that to get a User Access Token on the graph explorer UI itself. What must I be doing wrong?

Also, when I do the same for type=page, I always get an empty list for any keyword.

Comment: Is that kind of search still documented anywhere? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#searchtypes does not list this as one of the valid types.

Comment: I have seen some stack overflow older questions that seem to do something like this, so I was thinking maybe there is still some ways to do it. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948839/methods-of-searching-for-facebook-groups-by-keywords But I guess they have deprecated this

Comment: Yes, they have removed most of this stuff by now. With Facebook APIs, you can not go by answers that are half a decade old, you always have to check against the documentation to see what is still available.